# Can't call a method from a class, maybe a context issue. And how to make a pinned size of a SlideBox auto?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, accordion

As you can see from console, it can't call a function `slideDown()`, I'm guessing it's more like syntax error, or context, but don't really know how to bypass it.

And a bonus issue what I have is as you can see `@keyframe height: 200px;` BUT if we resize browser 200px isn't enough for text to be in, it already needs to be about 250px height. When I put height: auto it acts without animation AT ALL. Do you know how to set it due to actual size of content inside?

http://jsfiddle.net/cnvx6sd5/1/

[image: console error]

JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    class Aq
    {
            constructor()
            {
                    this.asks = document.querySelectorAll('.ask');

                    this.asks.forEach((ask) => ask.addEventListener('click', this.slideToggle));
            }
//      it's related on hiegth !!!
                slideToggle()
            {
                    let answer = this.parentNode.querySelector('.answer');

                    if(getComputedStyle(answer).display == 'none')
                            this.slideDown(answer);
                    else
                            this.slideUp(answer);
            }

            slideDown(answer)
            {
                    let handler = function()
                    {
                            answer.classList.remove('active_end');
                            answer.removeEventListener('animationend', handler);
                    }

                    answer.classList.add('active_start');
                    setTimeout(()=>{ answer.classList.add('active_end')}, 50);
                    answer.addEventListener('animationend', handler);
            }

            slideUp(answer)
            {
                    let handler = function()
                    {
                            answer.classList.remove('active_start');
                            answer.classList.remove('hide_start');
                            answer.addEventListener('animationend', handler);
                    }

                    answer.classList.add('hide_start');
                    answer.addEventListener('animationend', handler);
            }

            slideUpAll()
            {

            }
    }
        new Aq;
})
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

.faq{
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.item{
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.ask{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.answer{
    background: #ff0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.active_start{
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
}

.active_end{
    animation: slideDown 1s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hide_start{
    animation: slideUp 1s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown
{
    0%{
        height: 0;
    }

    100%{
        height: 200px;
    }

}

@keyframes slideUp
{
    0%{
        height: 200px;
    }

    100%{
        height: 0px;
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>1</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="faq">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ask">0. Вопрос какой-то №1</div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ask">2. Вопрос какой-то №2</div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ask">3. Вопрос какой-то №3</div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ask">4. Вопрос какой-то №4</div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ask">5. Вопрос какой-то №5</div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should insert the console logs as text on Stack Overflow, instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slideDown` or `slideUp` method will not be called because of the context of `this`. `addEventListener` binds the `this` value to the element it is listening to. So you'll need to change the context of `this` to the `Aq` class.

You can do that by using the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method. Every function has this method which passes a value that should be used as the value for `this` and creates a new function with that value. Now `this` can refer to the `Aq` class and not the `<div class="ask">` element.

```
class Aq {

  constructor() {
    this.asks = document.querySelectorAll('.ask');
    const bindSlideToggle = this.slideToggle.bind(this);
    this.asks.forEach((ask) => ask.addEventListener('click', bindSlideToggle));
  }

  slideToggle() {
    let answer = this.parentNode.querySelector('.answer');
    if (getComputedStyle(answer).display == 'none')
      this.slideDown(answer);
    else
      this.slideUp(answer);
  }

}
```

Or you could use [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) in combination with an arrow function to bind the scope of `this` to the class at all times. But his is a new feature (currently in experimental phase) and can lack support on some browsers.

```
class Aq {

  constructor() {
    this.asks = document.querySelectorAll('.ask');
    this.asks.forEach((ask) => ask.addEventListener('click', this.slideToggle));
  }

  slideToggle = event => {
    let answer = this.parentNode.querySelector('.answer');
    if (getComputedStyle(answer).display == 'none')
      this.slideDown(answer);
    else
      this.slideUp(answer);
  }

}
```